# Crear Listas con BindingList C#

Tags: c#, lista, método

código para crear una bindingList:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Negocio;
using Entidades;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;  

private BindingList<EntidadEncabezado> CargarEncabezados()
    {
        Cuenta en = new Cuenta();
        BindingList<EntidadEncabezado> ee = new BindingList<EntidadEncabezado>();
        BindingList<EntidadEncabezado> tempee = new BindingList<EntidadEncabezado>();
        int IdEntidad = 0;
        ee.AllowNew = true;
        if (gridView2.SelectedRowsCount > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int[] Handles = ((GridView)gridCuentas.MainView).GetSelectedRows(); //Obtengo las filas seleccionadas en el gridView y las almaceno en un array.

            while ( i < gridView2.SelectedRowsCount) //--> Recorro el gridView. 'i' Me da el índice de la fila del gridView
            {
                // A un objeto de tipo 'Cuenta' le concateno la fila seleccionada. Al array le paso el indice de la fila actual.
                en = (Cuenta)(gridCuentas.MainView.GetRow(Handles[i]));
                IdEntidad = en.Entidad.IdEntidad; // Obtengo el IdEntidad para pasar como parámetro en el método 'EntidadEncabezado'.

                if (ee.Count != 0) //Si la lista tiene elementos almacenados, le sumo el nuevo objeto con el IdEntidad obtenido
                {
                    tempee = NEntidadEncabezado.EntidadEncabezado(Convert.ToInt32(IdEntidad));
                }
                else //Si la lista no tiene elementos, creo una nueva lista 
                {
                    ee = new BindingList<EntidadEncabezado>(NEntidadEncabezado.EntidadEncabezado(Convert.ToInt32(IdEntidad)).ToList());
                }
                //Concateno las 2 BindingLists y las guardo en "ee"
                ee = new BindingList<EntidadEncabezado>(ee.Concat<EntidadEncabezado>(tempee).ToList());

                i++; // Actualizo el índice
            }
        }
        return ee;
    }
```

Al debuguear el código veo que va todo bien, solo que no veo por qué motivo no me está generando la lista.
**Aclaraciones**

1. La clase 'Cuenta' tiene una propiedad Entidad, de la cual obtengo el IdEntidad.
2. La clase EntidadEncabezado solo tiene las propiedades IdEntidad y NombreEntidad.
3. Estoy usando controles de Devexpress pero las BindingList funcionan igual que en WinForms.

Comment: Cual lista es la que te guarda el ultimo elemento? La lista `ee` o `tempee` ?

Comment: Lo debugueo y veo que pasa siempre por ee, acabo de probar cambiando el signo '!=' por el '>0' pero sigue igual. No me está almacenando la lista en ee.

Answer (score 1):

En todas las pasadas estas haciendo

```
ee = new BindingList<EntidadEncabezado>(NEntidadEncabezado.EntidadEncabezado(Convert.ToInt32(IdEntidad)).ToList());
```

y

```
ee = new BindingList<EntidadEncabezado>(ee.Concat<EntidadEncabezado>(tempee).ToList());
```

Por lo cual parece que siempre estas creando una nueva lista.. y solo va a quedar el ultimo elemento creado. No entiendo mucho la lógica de usar dos listas, ni se que hacen los procedimientos a los que llamas, pero no deberías agregare elementos a la lista en lugar de crear una binding list en cada vuelta?

Comment: Es correcto lo que decís pero al momento de agregar los elemento con .Add(..) lanza una excepción, entonces tuve que utilizar esta forma. Igualmente acabo de encontrar el verdadero problema, el SQLDataReader de mi Capa de Datos no tiene filas que mostrar, entonces creo que el procedimiento que uso está mal diseñado.

Comment: Hice una nueva pregunta para resolver esto en [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84190/crear-stored-procedure-que-cree-una-nueva-tabla-sqlserver-2014]

Comment: ok.. entonces acepta la respuesta, o borra la pregunta si no sirve, pero no dejes abierta esta y sin contestar