# Crear Stored Procedure que cree una nueva tabla - SQLServer 2014

Tags: stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Necesito crear un procedimiento que me cree una nueva tabla a partir de seleccionar una o varias entidades. La selección del 'IdEntidad' la hago desde un gridView en la capa de presentación en Visual Studio.
Lo que tengo es esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_LlenarRecursosEntidades] 

@IdEntidad int

AS
BEGIN

declare @_identidad int = -1
if @IdEntidad is null set @IdEntidad = @_identidad

select E.IdEntidad, E.NombreEntidad from Entidad E
where E.IdEntidad = @IdEntidad

if object_id ('Resources') is not null
drop table Resources
begin try
    select distinct E.IdEntidad as ResourceID, E.NombreEntidad as ResourceName 
    into Resources
    from Entidad E
    where E.IdEntidad = @IdEntidad
            order by NombreEntidad 
end try
begin catch
    return -1
end catch
END
```

El problema es que en la tabla me almacena solo una entidad cuando en mi código le paso el 'IdEntidad' de varias Entidades.
**Aclaraciones**
*En mi DB tengo la tabla Entidad (IdEntidad "int", NombreEntidad "varchar")*

Comment: deberias aclarar cual es el problema...

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregué

Comment: si idEntidad es un entero (uno solo) como haces para pasarle una lista?

Comment: Es exactamente eso lo que no sé resolver. Necesito es que cada vez que reciba un 'IdEntidad' vaya almacenando esa Entidad en la nueva tabla.

Comment: lo que pasa es que este SP esta borrando la tabla cada vez que entra.. no deberias borrarla solo antes de entrar?? capaz necesitas dos SP..

Comment: Si, estoy creando otro SP para de alguna manera incluirlo en este

Comment: es que no.. como esta planteada tu solucion, que no esta buena, lo mejor que podrias hacer es o pasar un parametro a este que diga si tiene que borrar o no la tabla, o si no desde donde llamas, llamar primero a borrar la tabla.. igual.. todo esto que estas planteando no funciona si tu sistema anda en red. que no lo se..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, lo pude solucionar usando 3 stored procedures, quizá no sea muy óptimo pero me sirvió por el momento.
Ya que necesito que los datos que me va a mostrar la tabla van a cambiar cada vez que se llame al método que estoy utilizando en mi capa de presentación, creé un stored procedure que me elimine la tabla Resources si ya existe:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_EliminarTablaResources] 
as
if OBJECT_ID('Resources') is not null
drop table Resources
```

Después creé otro para que me volviera a crear la tabla Resources:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CrearTablaResources] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT 
create table Resources(
Id int Primary key Identity(1,1),
ResourceId int not null,
ResourceName varchar(max) not 
END
```

Y finalmente creé otro sp para que llene la tabla Resources con los datos de las filas que selccioné en mi gridview de la capa presentación pero que no cargue el dato si ya existe:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertIntoResources] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@IdEntidad int
AS
declare @NombreEntidad varchar(max)
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
if exists(
select ResourceId, ResourceName from Resources
    where ResourceId = @IdEntidad)
    Begin
    --set @NombreEntidad = (select NombreEntidad from Entidad where IdEntidad = @IdEntidad)
        raiserror('Err -998: El registro ya existe.', 1, 10)
        return -998
    end
    Else 
    begin
    set @NombreEntidad = (select NombreEntidad from Entidad where IdEntidad = @IdEntidad)
        insert into Resources (ResourceID, ResourceName)
        values (@IdEntidad, @NombreEntidad)
    end
END
```

Comment: porque dropear la tabla y volverla a crear, no alcanzaba con borrar la info que tenia? y como te dije, espero que esto no sea un sistema en red, si nos los usuarios van a ver cualquier cosa

Comment: Y por qué no me das una ayuda que sirva en vez de decirme todo lo que sé?

Comment: Porque desconozco tu problema completo, o porque estas usando esta solucion para el problema que no explicaste por completo. Yo veo solo una parte parcial de tu problema. Pregunte varias veces si era un sistema en red, pq de ser asi no podes usar esta solucion. tal vez tu solucion sea solamente un query que devuelva todo lo que estas metiendo en esa tabla?

Comment: El problema completo no importa en este caso, yo quería una respuesta concreta a este problema. No es un sistema en red, si fuese asi lo hubiera aclarado en su momento. Y si dropeo la tabla es porque lo necesito así para otro caso, ya sé que podría haber hecho un update o delete y volverla a cargar.

Comment: Entonces si te sirve esta perfecto.

Answer (score 2):

Usa dos procedimientos, el primero para crear la tabla:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Crear_entidades

AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 

  SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
   ....
);'; 

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql; 
END
GO
```

Y otro para insertar datos. Que es lo mismo, pero en lugar de la Query de create tienes que meter la de insert.

Vamos, lo que tienes que hacer es insertar las querys normales de SQL dentro de la "variable" @SQL, para luego ejecutarla.

*Echale un ojo a este:* https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39249/stored-procedure-create-table-from-variable-with-variable-constraint

Comment: esto no tiene nada que ver con el problema que tiene OP